# Minimum variance solution to a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, regularization

For an under-determined linear system $\boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol{b}$ the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%5C%E2%5C%80%5C%93Penrose_inverse#Minimum_norm_solution_to_a_linear_system) $\boldsymbol{A^+}$ can be used to find the solution $\boldsymbol{x}_\text{L2} = \left\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\right\}$ with the minimum Euclidean norm $||\boldsymbol{x}||_2$ among all the solutions:

$$\boldsymbol{x}_\text{L2} = \boldsymbol{A}^+\boldsymbol{b}$$

The Euclidean norm selects the solution which minimises $\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2$. However this question concerns the case where the solution that minimises $\sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i - \mu)^2$ is sought where $\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i$. Is there a way to calculate this 'minimum variance' solution without resorting to numerical optimisation?

Consider an example that motivates the search for a minimum variance solution:

$$\boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol{b} = \begin{bmatrix}
1/2 &1/2 &0\\
0 &1/2 &1/2
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Say that $\boldsymbol{x}$ is unknown and is to be calculated then solutions are of the form

$$
\boldsymbol{x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 2\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ -1\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\omega
$$

for $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$. The minimum L2-norm solution is:

$$
\boldsymbol{x}_\text{L2} = \boldsymbol{A}^+\boldsymbol{b} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4/3 &-2/3\\
2/3 &2/3\\
-2/3 &4/3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2/3\\ 4/3\\ 2/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However in this case the minimum variance solution would give the original vector of ones however how can this be calculated?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense as it is posed: the only constraint is the minimum variance constraint, which is obviously obtained for $\vec{x} = 0$. You need to also have a constraint that relates it to the linear system.

Comment: @parsiad The constraint is $\boldsymbol{x}$ must be a line as given by the third equation. The problem could also be stated as finding $\omega$ that gives the minimum variance solution. The L2-norm solution is $\omega = 2/3$ and the minimum variance solution is $\omega = 1$. But aside from this simple example how could the minimum variance solution be found?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a bit late, but I got into the same problem and could not find any solution. So I worked out one.

Solution is

$x = A^T  (   A  A^T  )^{-1 }  ( b - A u z  ) +   u  z$

where   $u = ( 1, 1, ...., 1 )^T$
and the scalar z is

$z = [ u^T  A^T  ( A A^T )^{-1}  b ] / [ u^T  A^T  ( A A^T )^{-1}  A u ]$

You can find the details in arxiv 1906.09121